# Question on Corollary 5.2.9 in Spanier AT

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> Let $0\to B'\xrightarrow{\alpha'}B\xrightarrow{\beta'}B''\to 0$ be a s.e.s. of modules and let $A$ be a module. There is an exact sequence
> $$0\to A*B'\xrightarrow{1*\alpha'}A*B\xrightarrow{1*\beta'}A*B''\to A\otimes B'\xrightarrow{1\otimes\alpha'}A\otimes B\xrightarrow{1\otimes\beta'}A\otimes B''\to 0$$

[image: .]

During th proof, it says that $H_q(C) =0$ if $q\neq 0$ and $H_0(C) =A$. But $C$ is an exact sequence. I don't understand why $H_0(C) =A$. I think it should be $0$. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is meant by "...free chain complex obtained by adding trivial groups on both sides"? Does this mean the deleted free resolution; i.e., $0 \to C_1 \to C_0 \to 0$? $A$ is not assumed to be free, so it seems strange to claim that adding a trivial group to $A$'s presentation would result in a free chain complex.

Comment: @kamills Actually, I'm confusing that part too. The book just stated like that.

Comment: I see. Well, the claim about the homology of $C$ that you're asking about would be true if what I said above is correct; i.e., if $C$ is the chain complex $0 \to C_1 \xrightarrow{f} C_0 \to 0$. The homology at position $0$ is the quotient of $C_0$ by the image of $f$, but the image of $f$ is the kernel of the map $g: C_0 \to A$, and the quotient $C_0/\ker{g}$ is isomorphic to the image of $g$, which is all of $A$. Hence $H_0(C) \cong A$. So, perhaps if you can sort out what is meant by that sentence about "adding trivial groups," you'll have a resolution to your question.

Comment: @kamills  That really makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @kamills Why not an official answer? Spanier says that $C$ is *free* which clearly shows that adding trivial groups on both sides means $C_i = 0$ for $i \ne 0,1$. In particular $A$ (which is in general not free) does not belong to $C$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Oh! I actually do understand Spanier's wording now. He means to add trivial groups indefinitely on both sides to actually obtain a chain complex with modules in every degree. When I originally read his proof I thought, "but there already are trivial modules on both sides," as in in degrees -1 and 2. I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Spanier means by the complex $C$ is the deleted free resolution of $A$; that is, take the free resolution

$0 \to C_1 \xrightarrow{f} C_0 \xrightarrow{g} A \to 0$

and remove $A$ from it to obtain the complex

$0 \to C_1 \xrightarrow{f} C_0 \to 0$. (The words "trivial groups(/modules) on both sides" mean that we should operate with the understanding that $C_i = 0$ for all $i \neq 0,1$, so that this chain complex extends in both directions but with trivial groups at every position besides at positions $0$ and $1$.)

We can now compute the homology of $C$. By definition of $C$, $H_i(C) = 0$ for all $i \neq 0,1$.

At position $1$, we have $H_1(C) = \ker(f)$, but the free resolution of $A$ is an exact sequence so $\ker f = 0$, hence $H_1(C) = 0$.

At position $0$, we have $H_0(C) = C_0/\text{im}(f)$. By exactness of the free resolution of $A$, $\text{im}(f) = \ker(g)$ so that $H_0(C) = C_0/\ker(g) \cong \text{im}(g) = A$. The displayed isomorphism is commonly referred to as the "first isomorphism theorem" and the last equality holds by exactness of the free resolution of $A$.